# How to modify or setup the default format of the easyui-datebox control using Asp Classic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Within the code (see below/ attached) I modified the date format , but opening again the calendar  it display  date in a wrong data/format.
$(function()
{

```
 $('#txtDate').datebox({
onSelect: function(date){
    var m = new String(date.getMonth()+1)
    var newD = date.getDate() + "/" + m+ "/" + date.getFullYear()
    $('#txtDate').datebox('setValue', newD)
    }
});
  $.fn.datebox.defaults.formatter = function(date){
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var m = date.getMonth()+1;
    var d = date.getDate();
    return (d<10?('0'+d):d)+'-'+(m<10?('0'+m):m)+'-'+y;
};
$.fn.datebox.defaults.parser = function(s){
    alert("s = " + s)
    if (!s) return new Date();
    var ss = s.split('-');
    var y = parseInt(ss[0],10);
    var m = parseInt(ss[1],10);
    var d = parseInt(ss[2],10);
    if (!isNaN(y) && !isNaN(m) && !isNaN(d)){
        return new Date(d,m-1,m);
    } else {
        return new Date();
    }
};
});
<body><input class="easyui-datebox" id="txtDate"  ></input></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$('.easyui-datebox').datebox({
        formatter : function(date){
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var m = date.getMonth()+1;
            var d = date.getDate();
            return (d<10?('0'+d):d)+'-'+(m<10?('0'+m):m)+'-'+y;
        },
        parser : function(s){

            if (!s) return new Date();
            var ss = s.split('-');
            var y = parseInt(ss[2],10);
            var m = parseInt(ss[1],10);
            var d = parseInt(ss[0],10);
            if (!isNaN(y) && !isNaN(m) && !isNaN(d)){
                return new Date(y,m-1,d)
            } else {
                return new Date();
            }
        }

    });
```